# scheme environment model closure issue

Tags: scheme, eval, apply, sicp

[SICP 3.2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html) introduce environment model to replace substitution model.

I did following test while learning this part:

```
(define a1 1)
(define (f1) a1)
(f1) ; return 1
(define (f2) (define a1 2) a1)
(f2) ; return 2
(define (f3) (define a1 2) (f1))
(f3) ; return 1，not 2
```

The last expression was beyond my expectations.

A sentence token from SICP

> A procedure object is applied to a set of arguments by constructing a frame, binding the formal parameters of the procedure to the arguments of the call, and then evaluating the body of the procedure in the context of the new environment constructed. The new frame has as its enclosing environment the environment part of the procedure object being applied.

According to this rule, When invoke `f1` inside `f3`, a new environment is created, and its enclosing environment is global, not environment (call `E1`) created when invoke `f2`. For me, `E1` should be the enclosing environment.

For brevity, I draw two pictures depicting the environment 
[image: env when define functions]
[image: env when invoke f3]

A similar C example:

```
int a = 1;
void f1() {
    printf("a = %d from f1\n", a);
}
void f2() {
    int a = 2;
    printf("a = %d from f2\n", a);
}
void f3() {
    int a = 2;
    f1();
}
int main() {
    f2();
    f3();
    return 0;
}
print:
a = 2 from f2
a = 1 from f1
```

Is there anything I am missing ? or why does `f3` in both `Scheme` and `C` print 1 instead of 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that in the environment model, when you define a function, actually you obtain a *closure*, that is a couple (function, environment in which to evaluate the *free* variables of the function). A free variabile is a variable mentioned in the function which is not a parameter or a local variable, so that, when the function is actually executed, it is searched in the environment part of the closure.

So, when you define `f1`, the closure returned has as environment the current global environment, in which `a1` has value `1`.

In your definition of `f2`, you define `a1` as `2`. This is a *local* definition, so that in the body, the value of `a1` is searched first in the local environment, and `2` is found.

In the definition of `f3`, you define again `a1` as `2`, and again this binding is present in the local environment, but you call `f1`, which is a closure, and during *its* esecution the value of `a1` is searched according to the definition of `f1` (and the value found is that present in the environment used at the closure building time, that is `1`.)

This way of interpreting variables is called *static binding*, in contrast to *dynamic binding*, in which the result would have been `2`.

Note that both C and Scheme uses static binding, and your C example show exactly this: the result of calling `f3` is `1`, since this is the value printed inside `f1`. The image, on the other hand, is not correct. You should think of an environment as a set of frames, each of them containing bindings (i.e. couples variable, current value), connected to other frames. So that the closure of `f1`, `f2`, `f3`are different.

The following picture shows the growth of the global environment:

[image]

`E1` is the global environment after the definition of `a1`. `E2` after the definition of `f1`, you can note that the value of `f1` is a closure pointing to the second frame (this to allow recursive definitions, since `f1` can in principle call itself). In the closure the value of `a1` is the value present in `E1`. `E3` is the environment after the definition of `f2`, with  the closure pointing first to the local environment, where `a1` is equal to `2`, then to the current global environment. Finally `E4` is the global environment after the definition of `f3`. Note that the new closure has again a local environment with `a2` equal to `2`.

When `f3` is called, the `f1` inside its body is retrieved as the value of `f1` in `E2`, and when `f1` is evaluated, then `a1 = 1` is used.

With dynamic binding, on the other hand, there is no need to create closures. Each function is evaluated in the current environment, which is the global environment extended with the parameter bindings and the local definitions. So you could imagine that the global environment now has simply this form:

[image]

but when `f3` is evaluated, the `(define a1 2)` add a new frame to the environment:

[image]

and with this environment is evaluate the last form, `(f1)`. During this evaluation, `f1` is retrieved in the environment, and *its* body is again evaluated in the *same* (unique) environment, in which `a2` has value `2`.

Comment: Hi Renzo, I have updated the `C` example.and attach two picture  depicting the environment when invoke `f3`. I think I get your point.In static binding, global env should be the enclosing environment and `E1` should be in dynamic binding.Is it right ?

Comment: Aha, The thing I have missed is that environment is a sequence of frames. And to be honest, I have no idea how frames make up the environment until see your picture. BTW, how do dynamic binding languages eval `f3` return 2, could you  draw another picture explaining this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is the internal define in `f2`.

If you try this program, which uses `set!` instead of `define`
you will get the result you expect (for clarity I renamed the last 
function to `f3`).

```
(define a1 1)
(define (f1) a1)
(f1) ; return 1
(define (f2) (set! a1 2) a1)
(f2) ; return 2
(define (f3) (define a1 2) (f1))
(f3) ; return 1，not 2
```

Output:

```
1
2
2
```

Now the reason you don't see that behaviour in the original program is due to
the internal define:

```
 (define (f2) (define a1 2) a1)
```

The internal define will expand to

```
 (define (f2) 
   (letrec ((a1 2))
     a1))
```

which if we rename the variables is:

```
 (define (f2) 
   (letrec ((a2 2))
     a2))
```

So internal define will allocate a new variable and thus the original location to which a1 was bound is not affected - and thus keeps the value 1.

Note: In the REPL (top-level) using `define` to define an already defined variable is equivalent to `set!. That is top-level define and internal define are two separate concepts.

Comment: In your above code,`(define (f2) 
   (letrec ((a1 2))
     a2))`, where does `a2` come from? or is a typo and actually is `a1` ?

Comment: Typo - sorry. For the official description of internal definitions see this section in R5RS:  http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/doc/r5rs-8.html#Internal-definitions